# Uncheck checkboxes and re-check previous checkbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code snippet. Initially we have a category which is represented in the blue box and contains a row of checkboxes `checked` already. Then, we can add other sections which generate another row of checkboxes and so on. The validation occurs if I have selected a checkbox in a row, then when I check another one within the same column, it automatically unchecks the previous one and checks the newly selected.

The issue that I am having is that if I uncheck a checkbox manually, it should check the previous one that was checked within the same column and within the same category (blue box). Can someone please help me with this ?

```js
$(".main").on('change', '.js-cars-item [type="checkbox"]', function() {
  var idx = $(this).closest('li').index(); //Get the index - Number in order
  var chk = $(this).is(":checked"); //Get if checked or not
  var obj = this; //Checkbox object

  $(this).closest('.cars').find('.js-cars-item').each(function() { //Loop every js-cars-item
    //Find the checkbox with the same index of clicked checkbox. Change disabled property
    $(this).find('li:eq(' + idx + ') [type="checkbox"]').not(obj).prop("checked", false);
  });

  var checkeds = [];
  $(this).closest(".cars").find(".cars-item input:checkbox:checked").each(function(index) {
    checkeds[index] = $(this).attr('id');
  });
  console.clear();
  console.log("These are checked:", checkeds);
})

$('.js-add-category').click(function() {

  var categoryContent = `<div class="cars">

<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-3" checked>
      <label for="car-1-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-3" checked>
      <label for="car-2-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-3" checked>
      <label for="car-3-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button type="button" class="js-add-section">Add Section</button>
<button type="button" class="js-save-section">Add Section</button>
</div> <br>`

  $('.main').append(categoryContent);

});


$(document.body).on('click', 'button.js-add-section', function() {
  var sectionContent = `<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-6>
      <label for="car-1-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
      <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-6>
      <label for="car-2-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
      <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-6>
      <label for="car-3-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul> </div>`

  $(this).closest('.cars').append(sectionContent);

});

$(document.body).on('click', 'button.js-save', function() {
 alert('hi');
});
```

```css
.cars-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

ul {
  /* Added to fully show console in snippet */
  margin: 2px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.cars {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="js-add-category">Add Category</button> <br> <br>

<div class="main">

  <div class="cars">

    <div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-3" checked>
          <label for="car-1-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-3" checked>
          <label for="car-2-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-3" checked>
          <label for="car-3-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="js-add-section">Add Section</button>
    <button type="button" class="js-save-section">Add Section</button>
    <br>

    <div class="section">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
```

Comment: `$(".main").on('change', '.js-cars-item input[type="checkbox"]', function() {}`  You'll need `input` in front of the `[type]`.

Comment: You getting any errors?  Any break points being hit/missed?

Comment: The issue is that I want to re-check the previously checked checkbox when I manually uncheck a box.

Comment: @DMcCallum83 Why is that needed? Is there any other element type that matches `type="checkbox"`?

Comment: Where is your code that's supposed to check the previous box? There should be something that does `if (!chk) { code to check previous box }`, but I don't see it in the question.